# Datepicker not showing in Modal box JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, modal-dialog

I am using modal box in my page. when i click text-field where datapicker is added, it is not showing anything. But in 'inspect element of chrome' i can see that 'hasDatepicker' class is already added up. But how ever cant see the datepicker inside modal box.

I tried datepicker in the same page where modal box exists, then the datepicker is working.

code is

```
         <script>
           $(function() {
              $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
           });
        </script>
```

Html code is

```
                    <div class="">
             <a type="button" class="openmodalbox" href="javascript:void(0);" value="Modal box" title="Add Allergy">
                       add
                   <span class="modalboxContent">
            <div class="headdin_div">Add Allergies</div>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Allergies</td><td><input class="inp_padd" type="text"></input></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Type</td><td><input class="inp_padd" type="text"></input></td></tr>
                     <tr> <td>First observed</td><td><input type="text" class="inp_padd" id="datepicker"></input></td></tr>
                     <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" class="save_button_style" value="Save" /></td></tr>
                </table>      
                </span> 
                </a>    
                 </div>
```

Is it the problem with modal box? Or datepicker property?

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: could you post html, and js code for modal as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've changed your code a little bit:

```
<div class="">
        <a type="button" class="openmodalbox" href="#1" value="Modal box" title="Add Allergy" id="btn">add </a>
        <span class="modalboxContent">
                <div class="headdin_div">
                    Add Allergies</div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Allergies</td>
                        <td><input class="inp_padd" type="text"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Type</td>
                        <td><input class="inp_padd" type="text"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First observed</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="inp_padd" id="datepicker"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" class="save_button_style" value="Save" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </span>
    </div>
```

and js:

```
            $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();


            $(".modalboxContent").dialog({
                autoOpen: false
            });

            $("#btn").click(function () {
                $(".modalboxContent").dialog('open');
            });
        });
```

it's working fine now:

http://jsfiddle.net/ye24d/

Comment: If you don't mind, i have one more doubt..css property of modelbox is overridden by datepicker css..how can i prevent it?

Comment: try using google jQuery_ui cdn http://jsfiddle.net/ye24d/2/ , it's just the matter of customizing the jquery ui css, cause they both using same css classes and files

Answer (score 1):

here is Demo to code which working [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/KKhZg/321/)

you need to connect your code to input file or to button and to add link to ui css and jquery ui . you can see it in the link above.

html code :

```
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="fromDate" name="fromDate"/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate"/>

​
```

java script code :

```
$(function() {
        var dates = $( "#fromDate, #toDate" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "fromDate" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
    });​
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply...But my problem is that datepicker is not working inside modalbox (modal popup)

Comment: can you able to insert your code to jsFiddle ,it will be more easy to see your full code?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is because your modal box blockout every thing using z-index property. You have to override the class of datapicker and assign it z-index property greater than the z-index of modal dialog. Datepicker will work fine.

Comment: How exactly? Datepickers z-index is -1 and modal box z-index 9999

Comment: then z-index of datepicker would be greater than 9999.